# Tensor Product of Submodules

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, tensor-products

In Keith Conrad's text on [Tensor Products](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/linmultialg/tensorprod2.pdf), he states on Page 8 of the text that for a fixed ring $R$ and $R$-modules $M$, $M'$, $N$ and $N'$, and maps $f:M\to M'$, $g:N\to N'$ that $\text{ker}(f)\otimes_R N$, strictly speaking is not a submodule of $M\otimes_R N$ (and similarly for $M\otimes_R\text{ker}(g)$).

The question that I have in mind is:

> Given a fixed ring $R$ and $R$-modules $M$, $N$ with submodules $M'$ and $N'$ respectively, with respective inclusion maps $i:M'\to M$ and $j:N'\to N$, is it possible for (1) $M'\otimes_R N'$ to not be a submodule of $M\otimes_R N$, and (2) $i\otimes j$ to be not injective?

Answer (score 10):

It might be good to record several examples of this, so here is another:

Take $R =\mathbb Z$ (so modules are just abelian groups), and let
$M' = 2 \mathbb Z \subset  \mathbb Z = M$, and $N' = N  = \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$
(so the inclusion map $j$ is the identity).  Then each of $M\otimes N$ and $M'\otimes N' = M'\otimes N$ is isomorphic to $N$, but $i\otimes j$ is the zero map.

Comment: Sorry but why $M'\otimes N'$ is not the zero module?

Comment: @user150248 if you have isomorphic $R$-modules $M \cong P$ and $N \cong Q$, then $M \otimes_R N \cong P \otimes_R Q$.   In the example given in the above answer, $R = \mathbf Z$, $M' \cong \mathbf Z$, and $N' = \mathbf Z/2\mathbf Z$. Therefore $M' \otimes_R N' \cong \mathbf Z \otimes_{\mathbf Z} N' \cong N' \not= 0$.

Comment: @KCd $M'$ is not $\mathbb{Z}$ it is $2 \mathbb{Z}$, so $M' \otimes N'$ would be zero, right?

Comment: @Artus, no. You can't factor 2 out of terms in $M'$. As I wrote before, if $f \colon M \to P$ and $g \colon N \to Q$ are $R$-module isomorphisms then $f \otimes g \colon M \otimes_R N \to P \otimes_R Q$ is an $R$-module isomorphism. In Matt E's example, $2\mathbf Z \otimes_{\mathbf Z} (\mathbf Z/2\mathbf Z) \cong \mathbf Z \otimes_{\mathbf Z} \mathbf Z/2\mathbf Z \cong \mathbf Z/2\mathbf Z$, so it's not $0$. But in $\mathbf Z \otimes_{\mathbf Z} (\mathbf Z/2\mathbf Z)$, $2 \otimes 1 = 2(1 \otimes 1) = 1 \otimes 2 = 0$. That calculation can't be done in $M' \otimes \mathbf Z N'$.

Comment: In concrete terms, a $\mathbf Z$-bilinear map $b \colon 2\mathbf Z \times (\mathbf Z/2\mathbf Z) \to A$ to an abelian group $A$ is determined by its value on the pair $(2,1)$:a general element of $2\mathbf Z \times (\mathbf Z/2\mathbf Z)$ looks like $(2x,y \bmod 2)$ and $b(2x,y \bmod 2) = xyb(2,1)$.  You *can't* write $b(2,1)$ as $2b(1,1)$ since that makes no sense: $1$ is meaningless in $2\mathbf Z$.  An example of a nonzero $\mathbf Z$-bilinear map $b \colon 2\mathbf Z \times (\mathbf Z/2\mathbf Z) \to \mathbf Z/2\mathbf Z$ is $b(2x,y \bmod 2) = xy \bmod 2$, so the tensor product is not $0$.

Answer (score 6):

Let $R = k[x]/x^2$, let $M = N = R$, let $M' = N' = (x)$, and let $i, j\colon(x) \to R$ be inclusion.  Then $M' \otimes_R N' = (x) \otimes_R (x)$ is nonzero (see if you can prove this!) but under $i \otimes j$ the image of $M' \otimes_R N'$ in $M \otimes_R N = R \otimes_R R \simeq R$ is $(x)(x) = (x^2) = 0$.  Thus $i \otimes j$ is the zero map.